# "Bottom NSView's" button border line still appears in the "top NSView" after top View is presented

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsviewcontroller

I'm working on a "Mac OSX App" that has two view controllers, the app starts from the first view (bottom view) and later "Canvas view controller (top view)" is presented from the first view controller.
After presenting "CanvasViewController (top view)",
CanvasView appears correctly with its buttons on the top of bottom view however the border line of the button of the bottom view still appears. I have attached the images of the bottom and top views below.
It doesn't look like alpha value issue as it is set to 1.0, instead it is related to some things else in the viewController settings (ie. first responder or button state, etc).
How can I remove this bottom view's button border line when the top view is presented on the top?
Any solutions or helpful comments will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
// From bottom view's viewController
@interface MainMenuViewController : NSViewController
@end

@implementation MainMenuViewController
...
-(IBAction)presentNextViewWithAnimator:(id)sender{
    
    id animator = [[MyCustomAnimator alloc] init];
    CanvasViewController* viewController = [[CanvasViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CanvasViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    // presenting "topView" with custom animator
    [self presentViewController:viewController animator:animator];
}
...
@end



// From "top view's viewController"
@interface CanvasViewController : NSViewController
@end

@implementation CanvasViewController
... 
// "close" button
-(IBAction)closeCanvas:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewController:self];
}

// "refresh" button
-(IBAction)refreshCanvas:(id)sender{    
}
...
@end


// From the view presentation's custom animator
@interface MyCustomAnimator : NSObject <NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator>
@end

@implementation MyCustomAnimator

-(void) animatePresentationOfViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController
                         fromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController
{

    NSViewController* bottomVC = fromViewController;
    NSViewController* topVC = viewController;
    
    topVC.view.wantsLayer = YES;
    topVC.view.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay;
    topVC.view.alphaValue = 1.0f;
    
    [bottomVC.view addSubview:topVC.view];
    
    CGRect frame = NSRectToCGRect(bottomVC.view.frame);
    
    [topVC.view setFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(frame)];
    topVC.view.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    
    [NSAnimationContext
        runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext * context){
            context.duration = 0.5f;
            topVC.view.animator.alphaValue = 1.0f;
        } completionHandler:nil];
}
...
@end
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [bottomVC.view addSubview:topVC.view]; -> You have 2 views in view hierarchy. Therefore there is no change of first responder (the button is still there. You just put white layer color on top). Animations should not add subviews.

Comment: @MarekH
Thanks for your comments. I tried several ways to switch the first responder setting to the TopView and got some progress, not perfect though. I still need to do one time "click" on the topView (at any location) to remove the grey mark. Once then the grey mark doesn't appear again while navigating between topView and bottomView. I'll post further when I get some complete solution. Thanks.

Comment: Just use NSTabViewController and change tab. DO NOT ALTER VIEW HIERARCHY in animation. You continue to do something that will cause more troubles.

Comment: @MarekH, Definitely I will consider NSTabViewController. BTW, would you be kind to explain the reason why animator should not add subviews? Actually I'm implementing my app based on some tutorial code that uses addSubview in animator whenever presenting another viewController, so I just followed that practice. Once again, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Animations should not add views that are managed by other view controllers (your one was added to old one). You should use fromViewController.view.window.contentView and addSubview of the new vc there

Comment: @MarekH Thanks for your answer. Appreciate it.